# Datatables date range filter not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables

I'm trying to add a date range filter on a Datatable but im not able to get it working properly. The date comes out of a Mysql Database and get selected as:

```
DATE_FORMAT(or_plan_date,'%d-%m-%Y') or_plan_date1
```

The date format is there to convert it from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy. This select returns the value like "01-08-2020"

The date is presented in column 1 like:

```
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><a href='view_orders.php?id={$or_id}'>{$or_number}</a></td>";
                echo "<td>{$or_plan_date1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$order_week1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$pm_code}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$or_amount}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$de_name}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$cs_name}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$or_order_status}</td>";                 
            echo "</tr>";
```

The javascript for the datatable looks as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orders').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true,
        stateDuration: 120,
        dom:    "<'row'<'col-sm-2'l><'col-sm-3'B><'col-sm-4'<'toolbar'>><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
buttons: [{ extend: 'print', text:'<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print', className: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' }, 
{ extend: 'excel',text:'<i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i> Excel', className: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' },
{ extend: 'pdf',className: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' ,text:'<i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF' }] ,
lengthChange: true,
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([5, 6, 7]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
                $( select ).click( function(e) {
                 e.stopPropagation();
           });
            } );
        }
        
    } );
    $("div.toolbar").html('From <input name="min" id="min" type="date"> / <input name="max" id="max" type="date">');

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = new Date($('#min'));
            var max = new Date($('#max'));
            var startDate = new Date(data[1]);
            if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
            if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
            if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
            if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
        );

       
            var table = $('#orders').DataTable();

            // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
            $('#min, #max').change(function () {
                table.draw();
            });
        
} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/onyfw69v/

The current situation is:
when I select a date the table refreshes but doesn't show any value. The same is when i try to use the sorting in the header. When i try to sort any column all entries disappear.

The expected result:
When "min" is filled it should filter the date and show all the date's > min. The same is with the max but then <max.

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong and how it should be?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/onyfw69v/ This should be it

Comment: Well, I'd start by focusing on the sql, but if you're happy that that's all working, then fine.

Comment: oh im sorry, thats the current situation (not working properly). Even without the SQL it's not working properly. This is the format how i receive the Dates now from the database: https://jsfiddle.net/ae4kbd9n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following code and removed the sql DATE_FORMAT:

```
  $("div.toolbar").html('From <input name="min" id="min" type="date" value="0"> / <input name="max" id="max" type="date" value="0">');

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var min_date = document.getElementById("min").value;
      var min = new Date(min_date);
      var max_date = document.getElementById("max").value;
      var max = new Date(max_date);

      var startDate = new Date(data[1]);
      //window.confirm(startDate);
      if (!min_date && !max_date) {
        return true;
      }
      if (!min_date && startDate <= max) {
        return true;
      }
      if (!max_date && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );

  var table = $('#orders').DataTable();

  // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
  $('#min, #max').change(function() {
    table.draw();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it is the date format you use in `new Date()`. It must be a string representing a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format. In your code this format is reversed.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format

Best to not convert the date in your SQL to the output format, but to do that when you actually generate the output.

I tested this with the following code:

```
let date = new Date('2010-11-12');
alert(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

This resulted in:

> 11/12/2010

```
let date = new Date('12-11-2010');
alert(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

and this resulted in:

> Invalid Date

This might be browser dependent, but clearly it won't work with the `dd-mm-yyyy` format.